# Better way to use mysql count() or num_rows

Tags: mysql, select, count

I am using this mysql select query to check how many image exist to given category in the database. I want to keep upto 5 images for one category.

```
$q = "SELECT image_id FROM image_info
            WHERE category_id = 1 AND member_id = $userId";
$r = $mysqli->query($q) or trigger_error($mysqli->error." [$q]"); 

if($r->num_rows <= 4) {
    echo 'good';
    // my stuff 
} else {
    echo 'bad';
}
```

This is working for me. But I would like to know is there a way to use `mysql` `COUNT()` for this query? If so, what is the better way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: There are instances (noted on stackoverflow.com and other sites) where COUNT() returns incorrect values. So I believe num_rows should be used.

Comment: @tadman, Thank you for your suggestion. Can you show me how to create about query with using `COUNT()`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve

`num_rows` is better when the number of records are less as it is the number of result records fetched.

`count(*)` is the number of records in the database matching the query. Count(*) is more efficient than num_rows as in num_rows you are retrieving that many records from database and eventually passing those to PHP

---

```
"SELECT count(*) FROM image_info WHERE category_id ='".$userId."'";
```

Comment: how to use IF condition?

Comment: Just get the query result, no need to use `$r->num_rows`

Comment: @MySQLRockstar For a `COUNT()` statement like that, you should get one row or an error.